# What's a good way to optimise rendering a 2D tile game in XNA?

Tags: xna-4.0, 2d-games

EDIT: I've opted for the second approach as I got 150+ fps even when all 3 tile layers fill the entire screen.

EDIT 2: I read a lot about vertex buffer objects and how they would be great for static geometry and although I still have no idea how to turn my 2D tiles into a VBO and store it on the GPU memory, it definitely seems like the way to go if anyone else is looking for a fast way to render static geometry/quads.

I'm making a game like Super Meat Boy and was wondering if it would be better/faster to store level tiles in an array list and do a camera bounds overlap test to see if it should be rendered.

```
foreach(Tile tile in world.tiles) {
    if(Overlap(camera.bounds, tile))
        render(tile);
}
```

Or would a 2D array storing every grid square and only reading off between camera bounds be better?

```
int left = (int)(camera.position.x - camera.width/2);
int right = (int)(camera.position.x + camera.width/2) + 1;
int top = (int)(camera.position.y - camera.height/2); // WHY XNA DO YOU UPSIDE DOWN!!!
int bottom = (int)(camera.position.y + camera.width/2) + 1;
for(int x = left; x < right; x++) {
    for(int y = top; y < bottom; y++) {
        render(world.tiles[x][y]);
    }
}
```

The camera can fit 64*36 tiles on screen which is 2300 odd tiles to read off using the latter approach but is doing an overlap test with every tile in the level any better?  I read an answer about joining matching adjacent tiles into a larger quad and just repeating the texture (although I'm using a texture atlas so I'm not sure how to repeat a region on a texture).

Cheers guys.

Comment: What does Render ? Do you have Spritbatch begin/end in ?

Comment: What is need of camera for 2D render?

Comment: @Cyril ALFARO Yeh the batch begin and end are before and after these loops

Comment: @kunjee The camera is basically a class which allows me to easily convert world space positions to screen space positions using matrices and also this way I can take advantage of camera zooming and camera roll/rotation.

Comment: @Mazk1985 it is good trick when you have knowledge of 3D game and you are making 2D game. or I can say 2.5D game. But if you are directly starting with 2D it will be little overkill and add some learning curve. I suggest better go with only 2D and use tricks which there for 2D only games. It will make things done easy way.

Comment: @kunjee oh I'm ok with rendering 2D using a 3D environment. Because I've worked in the past with 3D software and level editors so I find it more natural to make a 2D game using an orthogonal camera.  I was more wondering if anyone knew of a better way to organise tiles.  I've optimised the rendering of the tiles as much as I can and now with real time lights, paralax and multiple tile layers I get 500+ fps on my pc Q9550, radeon 4780 so it's not really a problem any more but thank you for your comments man :)

Comment: @Mazk1985 always happy to help. Let me know if any more help needed and also when you game is out. :)

Comment: @kunjee I've recently started a list of people I want to thank once the game is released so I'll add you to the credits if you want. A pre alpha demo is out later today if you want to check it out.  It will be available on IndieDB (http://www.indiedb.com/games/double-jump) and my main site is Gemi Games (http://gemi-games.com)

Comment: @Mazk1985 sure. You can add me. Thanks. Do, I need to do anything. And you can contact me via twitter and can let me know if any further details/ help needed from my end. :)

Comment: @Mazk1985 I have given details explanation of graphics part, I hope that will answer your question and help you out. :)

Comment: @kunjee Hi Kunjee, Sorry I've been a bit busy lately. Thank you for the great explanation about the rendering.  It made me realise I'm still new to this and that there's way's to increase the framerate further.  To answer your question about any machine.  Currently it's supports any resolution but weak GPU's don't perform too well due to the real time lights and multiple fullscreen pixel shader passes.  I'm interested in this TPL and async method. I'll do some research on it and get back to you if I run into problems. Thank you again for the advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my past experience I can share the details. In 2D map, normally map is like 0 - N long. Now N is far longer then screen size. Now at first I tried to loading everything at once. But it is bit of a overhead. Ok, it was like very much of a overhead. And I endup with 0 FPS. As I want different kind of object for me. So, even repeating same object and saving memory is not working. Then I tried bounding things with reference to screen. So, objects are there and but they are not getting rendered. So, it is moved from away from draw pipe line. And game back to life.

Now, for further performance with C# 4.0 I can use TPL and async and await with draw. It is like better version of threading. So, you can throw stuff there and let it be render at will.

Here is deal wiht XNA or any kinda graphics library. There is complete graphics rendering pipeline. And that makes things whole lot slow. Specifically if PC is old and only have 64MB graphics card to support only wide screen. *Your game will be deployed to any kinda machine right??!!*

So, if I explain in language of XNA, update is simple code and run it as fast as it can, there is nothing to stop it. But draw is has complete pipe line ahead of it. And that is sole reason of having begin and end. So, after end it can start pushing things to pipe line. [Here] (http://classes.soe.ucsc.edu/cmps020/Winter11/readings/hlsl.pdf) article for reference.

So, here is a deal rendering pipeline is needed but there is no need that is should be slow and blocking. Just make it multi-threaded and things will quite faster for you. If you want more terse then you have to use C# at it fullest including Linked list and stuff. But that will be like last stage.

I hope I have given enough details to provide you an answer. Please let me know if any further details needed.